# CLion: Strangely needs no import for #1 class, but fails on equalls structured #2 class

Tags: c++, clion

I am an absolute C/C++ beginner who's struggling with that problem for 3 days now. As following, I have a class `Geometry` with header and .cpp definition files. Just take a look:

```
//Geometry.h
#ifndef PROJECT_GEOMETRY_H
#define PROJECT_GEOMETRY_H

#endif //PROJECT_GEOMETRY_H

#include <vector>

class Geometry
{
public:
    std::vector<Vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<Face> faces;

public:
    Geometry();
    ~Geometry();

public:
    void rotate(char axis, float degrees);
    void rotateAroundOrigin(char axis, float degrees, Vec3 origin);
    void transform(double x, double y, double z);
    void transform(Vec3 bar);
};
```

and also `Vec3.h and Face.h`

```
//Vec3.h
#ifndef PROJECT_VEC3_H
#define PROJECT_VEC3_H

#endif //PROJECT_VEC3_H

class Vec3
{
public:
    Vec3(double x, double y, double z);
    ~Vec3();

public:
    double distance(Vec3 n);
    void rotate(char axis, float deg);
    void rotateAroundOrigin(char axis, float deg, Vec3 origin);
    void rotateAroundOriginPrecomputed(char axis, float deg, Vec3 origin, float sine, float cosine);

private:
    void rZ(float deg, Vec3* origin, float* sine, float* cosine);
    void rY(float deg, Vec3* origin, float* sine, float* cosine);
    void rX(float deg, Vec3* origin, float* sine, float* cosine);

public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

[*Please comment if you also need the .cpp files*]

```
//Face.h
#ifndef PROJECT_FACE_H
#define PROJECT_FACE_H

#endif //PROJECT_FACE_

class Face
{
public:
    std::vector<Vec3*> vertices;

public:
    Face();
    Face(std::vector<Vec3> bar);
    ~Face();

public:
    Vec3 getMidpoint();
};
```

The problem is, that the generic type of `vertices` is recognized without even importing the class `Vec3` [Which is suspicious enough on its own], but `Face` instead is thought to be a *variable* by CLion and is treated as `not declared in this scope` when compiling [The latter one being logical, 'cause class not imported, right?], though `Vec3` stays quiet at compile-time.

All header files are in the same directory, `src/headers`

And **yes**, all files are referenced in `CMakeLists.txt`

[*And I just noticed that `Vec3.h` doesn't need to include `<vector>` (it all makes no sense!)*]

I'm so sure I did something so stupidly **wrong** that the C/C++ veterans out there will be laughing their heads off or thinking of how stupid one person can be when looking at my code.

Comment: Unrelated to CMake, please drop the tag.

Comment: There is no such thing as "importing" in C++.

Comment: Just checking, you know your #ifndef/#define/#endif lines don't do anything useful, right?

Comment: Most of us have the `#endif` at the *end* of the include file. And `Face.h` can get away with not including `<vector>` if it happens to get included after some other file that *does* include `<vector>`. `Vec3.h` doesn't use any vector, so it gets away free.

Comment: Finishing the comment many others have hinted at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard